# SPFX REACT WebPart file upload works in Workbench but not if it is deployed to SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, document-upload

I'm developed a react webpart and try uploading a file to a Libraby. While i test it in the Workbensh it works perfectly. After deploying the webpart to SPO, it fails.

the setup of sp:

```
sp.setup({ spfxContext: this.props.controller.context });
```

then i get the file like this:

```
var files: HTMLInputElement = document.getElementById("fileUpload") as HTMLInputElement;
```

I've using this code for my first try: This thorw an 404 Error

```
sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(
        this.props.controller.context.pageContext.web.serverRelativeUrl+ "/"+listName)
        .files.add(file.name, file, true)
        .then((data) =>{
          alert("File uploaded sucessfully");
        })
        .catch((error) =>{
          alert("Error is uploading "+error);
        });
```

After them i tried this:

```
this.props.controller.GetRootFolderById(Guid.parse(listId)).then(fld => {
             var folderId = fld.UniqueId;
             console.log("FolderId: " + folderId);
             var folder = sp.web.getFolderById(Guid.parse(folderId).toString());

            folder.files.add(file.name, file, true).then(x => {
                console.log("Progress ...");
                UploadDocument.Me.setState({ waitHidden: true });
            });
```

i get also the Error result:

```
  body: ReadableStream
  bodyUsed: false 
  ​headers: Headers 
  ​ok: false
  ​redirected: false 
  ​status: 404 ​
  statusText: "Not Found"
  ​type: "basic"
```

And this happens only if it is deployed, in workbench works both samples!

Can sombody help me to find a solution?

Regards
Wilfried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a document lib name: **InformationBlockDocument**

**service is given below to upload the file:**

```
public async fileUploadInDocumentLibrary(file: any){
   return this.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(this.siteRelativeUrl+`/InformationBlockDocument/`).files.add(file.name, file.content, true);
    //.then(_ => Logger.write("done"));

  }
```

**To get the file from server service is given below:**

```
public async getFileFromDocumentLibrary(){

   return await this.web
    .getList(this.siteRelativeUrl+`/InformationBlockDocument`).items
    .select('Id',
        'ItemLabel',
        'ItemNameProperty',
        'Modified',
        'Editor/Id',
        'Editor/Title',
        'Author/Id',
        'Author/Title',
        'File/Name',
        'File/ServerRelativeUrl'
       )
    .expand('Author', 'Editor', 'File')
    .get();

  }
```

**To call the service from controller**

```
await this.service
    .fileUploadInDocumentLibrary(file)
    .then((f: any) => {

       -- success
    });
```

**HTML Code in React Render method**

```
 <input type="file" onChange={(e) => this.onFileChangeHandler(e)} />
```

**On change method to upload the file**

```
  public  onFileChangeHandler  (event)  {
    // call the service with file param
    service.fileUploadInDocumentLibrary(event.target.files[0]).then(res=>{
    // success
    });  

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i get the file over input type file not from a library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i get the file from input type: file not from a library and when uploading occurs 404 Error on deployed system.

Comment: Please check the updated post. I think it will help you.

Comment: Sorry don't work if it is deployed.
but the error has changed:
Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [400] Bad Request ::> {"odata.error":{"code":"-2147024809, System.ArgumentException","message":{"lang":"de-DE","value":"Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl"}}}

Besides that, the file.content proerty does not exist, i got the file it self.
What is by you this.web, i have oly sp.web. Is here s.t. different?

Comment: Ok super, thanks for your help!
I found out, that it doesn't work if i make an api call between get filecontent and upload.

Comment: If you have still a problem. could you upload your code in git repository. I will check and back to you.